# java ${user.home} variable in linux

Tags: java, linux, hibernate, tomcat

I have a java application (.war) which I use `${user.home}/${project.build.finalName}/index` (in hibernate.properties) to save hibernate index.  I can deploy it in tomcat in windows without problem. but when I deploy in linux(ubuntu server 14.04)  ${user.home} will translate to `/usr/share/tomcat7/`  instead of `/var/lib/tomcat7`. the tomcat home (the webapp folder)  is in `/var/lib/tomcat7/` so the deployment would fail because it can't write to `/usr/share/tomcat7/`

which variable should I use to refer `/var/lib/tomcat7`?

thanks

Comment: I am not sure what is "hibernate index", so, this may be a dumb question, but why include it into your .war file instead of referencing local filesystem in such a non-portable way?

Comment: Show the code with which you try to deploy your webapp

Comment: actually that's what I don't want to. the index folder saves the index of hibernate full text search index. in windows by default when I deploy it the path will be inside of the application (tomcat\myapp\index), in linux I expect it to be  /var/lib/tomcat7/myapp/index. but it isnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is a system property set by default, called `catalina.home` that points to the tomcat installation root. You could use that (I think, in your case, it'll be set to /var/lib/tomcat7 like you want).

Additionally, you can set any system property during tomcat startup by adding it to CATALINA_OPTS environment variable. For example:

`CATALINA_OPTS=-Dfoo.bar=/some/path/to/hibernate/index /var/lib/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh start`

(the above is meant to be a bash command on a single line).

Comment: you are almsot right! ${catalina.home} default is /usr/share/tomcat7  the right answer should be  ${catalina.base} which refers to  /var/lib/tomcat7 :D solved